# How to Load .mat Folder and files

Tags: python, performance, opencv, mat

I am trying to load a .mat dataset into my dataframe. So, I am only able to load a single file at a time from the Folder TrainingSet1 with

```
 os.chdir('/Users/Ashi/Downloads/TrainingSet2')
 data = loadmat('A2001.mat')
```

And i am able to see the data in it, but how am i supposed to load the whole TrainingSet1 Folder, so that i can view the whole thing. 
Also, how could I view the .mat files as images?

Heres my code,

```
%reload_ext autoreload
   %autoreload 2
   %matplotlib inline 

   from fastai.vision import *
   from fastai.metrics import error_rate
   from mat4py import loadmat
   from pylab import*
   import matplotlib
   import os

   os.chdir('/Users/Ashi/Downloads/TrainingSet2')

   data = loadmat('A2001.mat')
   data
   {'ECG': {'sex': 'Male', 'age': 68,
     'data': [[0.009784321006571624,
    0.006006033870606647,
   ...This is roughly how the data looks like   

   imshow('A2001.mat',[])  
   ---------------------------------------------------------------            
   TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-52-23bbdf3a7668> in <module>
   ----> 1 imshow('A2001.mat',[])...A long error is displayed
   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It hard to tell from your post what is the input format, and what is your desired output format.

I am giving you an example of reading all the `.mat` files in the folder, and an example of how to show `data['data']` as image.

I hope the example is enough for you to keep advancing by your own.

I created a sample data set `'A2001.mat'`, `'A2002.mat'`, `'A2003.mat'` using MATLAB.
In case you have MATLAB installation, I recommend you to execute the following code for creating a sample input (in order for the Python sample to be reproducible):

```matlab
ECG.sex = 'Male';
ECG.age = 68;
data = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')) / 10; % Divide by 10 for simulating range [0, 0.1] instead of [0, 1]   
save('A2001.mat', 'ECG', 'data');

ECG.sex = 'Male';
ECG.age = 46;
data = im2double(imread('cell.tif'));
save('A2002.mat', 'ECG', 'data');

ECG.sex = 'Female';
ECG.age = 54;
data = im2double(imread('tire.tif'));
save('A2003.mat', 'ECG', 'data');
```

---

The Python code sample does the following:

- Get a list of all `mat` files in the folder using `glob.glob('*.mat')`.
- Iterate `mat` files, load data from the files, and append the data to a list.
  The result of the loop is a list named `alldata`, containing data from all `mat` files.
- Iterate `alldata` and showing `data['data']` as an image.
  (Assuming `data['data']` is the matrix you want to show as an image).

Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mat4py import loadmat
import glob
import os

os.chdir('/Users/Ashi/Downloads/TrainingSet2')

# Get a list for .mat files in current folder
mat_files = glob.glob('*.mat')

# List for stroring all the data
alldata = []

# Iterate mat files
for fname in mat_files:
    # Load mat file data into data.
    data = loadmat(fname)

    # Append data to the list
    alldata.append(data)


# Iterate alldata elelemts, and show images
for data in alldata:
    # Assume image is stored in matrix named data in MATLAB.
    # data['data'], access data with string 'data', becuase data is a dictionary
    img = data['data']

    # Show data as image using matplotlib
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show(block=True) # Show image with "blocking"
```

---

### Update:

The ECG data is not an image but a list of 12 data samples.

The internal structure of the data (after `data = loadmat(fname)`) is:

- Parent dictionary named `data`.

  - `data` contains a dictionary in `data['ECG']`.

    - `data['ECG']['data']` is a list of 12 lists.

The following code iterates the `mat` files and displays the ECG data as a graph:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mat4py import loadmat
import glob
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir('/Users/Ashi/Downloads/TrainingSet2')

# Get a list for .mat files in current folder
mat_files = glob.glob('*.mat')

# List for stroring all the data
alldata = []

# Iterate mat files
for fname in mat_files:
    # Load mat file data into data.
    data = loadmat(fname)

    # Append data to the list
    alldata.append(data)


# Iterate alldata elelemts, and show images
for data in alldata:
    # The internal structure of the data is a dictionary with a dictionary.
    ecg = data['ECG']
    data = ecg['data'] # Data is a list of lists

    # Convert data to NumPy array
    ecg_data = np.array(data)

    # Show data as image using matplotlib
    #plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.plot(ecg_data.T)  # Plot the data as graph.
    plt.show(block=True)  # Show image with "blocking"
```

---

Result:

`A0001.mat`:
[image]

`A0002.mat`:
[image]

---

### Graph with labels:

```
# Iterate alldata elements, and show images
for data in alldata:
    # The internal structure of the data is a dictionary with a dictionary.
    ecg = data['ECG']
    data = ecg['data'] # Data is a list of lists

    # Convert data to NumPy array
    #ecg_data = np.array(data)

    # Show data as graph using matplotlib
    # Iterate data list:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        # Plot the data as graph.
        # Set labels d0, d1, d2...
        plt.plot(data[i], label='d'+str(i))

    plt.legend()  # Add legend
    plt.show(block=True)  # Show image with "blocking"
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: hey @Rotem,  that did not work. i neither have any kind of error nor the image.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem without the data. Can you post `A2001.mat` and `A2002.mat` somehow?

Comment: hey @Rotem, are u asking for the data inside those two mat files? so should i print it out?

Comment: I am asking for the files. Unless you can post the code for creating the files (MATLAB code I assume).

Comment: hey @Rotem. the files are too big like 2gb. I could send u the images of how the data looks like inside those files. other than this  i also have another issue with my code [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111371/regular-expression-for-extracting-label-from-location] . pls help me with this.

Comment: hey @Rotem, i sent u two files. and no they are not big.

Comment: The internal structure of the `mat` files is too complicated to guess. I updated my post. The data is not an image, but a list of 12 samples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211322/discussion-between-mukesh-and-rotem).

Comment: Hey @Rotem, those two files with graphical data, why dont they have labels?

Comment: After executing `ecg = data['ECG']`, there are: `ecg['age']` and ecg['sex']. Labels are not automatic. You need to add the labels by code. I updated my post to add labels, but they are kind of meaningless (unless the order is documented or standard).